# Login button is unresponsive-servlet is not called

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jsp, autowired

When i click the login button nothnig is happening somebody pls help me out.Iamtrying to create login form but the form action is not mapping to servlet
   Below are the files

Login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<style>
form {
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 45%;
}

img.avatar {
        width: 40%;
}

button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
    padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>


<body>
    <form  name="login" action="login" method="post">
          <div class="imgcontainer">
                <img src="C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\packing_final.jpg"
                alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
        </div>
        <div class=container>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><b>Username</b></label> <input type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter UserName" name="username" required></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td><label><b>Password</b></label> <input type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit">Login</button>
                        <!-- <button type="submit" onClick="parent.location='JSP/signUp.jsp'">SignUp</button> -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember
                        me</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
                        &nbsp; <a href="#">Forgot password?</a></td>
                </tr> -->

            </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet Code is like this.The first sysout itself is not printing

```
package com.packing.software.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.packing.software.bean.LoginBean;
import com.packing.software.dao.LoginDao;
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        System.out.println("inside servet");

        String userName= request.getParameter("username");
        String password= request.getParameter("password");
        LoginBean loginBean =new LoginBean();
        loginBean.setUserName(userName);
        loginBean.setPassword(password);
        LoginDao loginDao=new LoginDao();
        try{
            String userValidate= loginDao.authenticateUser(loginBean);
            if(userValidate.equals("Admin_Role")){
                System.out.println("admin");
                HttpSession session=request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("Admin", userName);
                request.setAttribute("userName", userName);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/JSP/admin.jsp").forward(request,response);
            }
        }catch(IOException | ServletException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>JavaLogin</display-name>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>JSP/login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>LoginAction</display-name>
<servlet-name>LoginAction</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.packing.software.controller.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>LoginAction</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- 
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>LogoutServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.login.controller.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/LogoutServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> -->
</web-app>
```

Project structre is like this:

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

```
   Change Code login.jsp 

    <form  action="login" method="post">

  change code web.xml file 

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login_Action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.packing.software.controller.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login_Action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login_data</url-pattern>`enter code here`
    </servlet-mapping>
```